# C# JavaScriptSerializer serialize fields that not exists in interface but do exists in original object

Tags: c#, .net, json, interface, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to serialize an object without some fields.
I've tried to define interface without those fields, and then cast and serialize it but the `JavaScriptSerializer` includes those fields as well.

```
interface iStam {
    public int a {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Stam :iStam{
    private int _a = 0;
    public int a {
        get {return _a;}
        set {_a = value;}
    }
    public int b = 0;
}


void fun() {
    Stam s = new Stam();
    /*
    s.a == 0;
    s.b == 0;
    */
    iStam _s = (iStam) s;
    /*
    _s.a == 0;
    _s.b Not exists!  compilation error.
    */

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer ();
    Console.WriteLine(jss.Serialize(_s));
}
```

Expected:

```
{
    "a":0
}
```

Got:

```
{
    "a":0,
    "b":0,
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here seems to be that `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize()` accepts an `object` argument, and not a generic type, and it serializes the object based on its class signature not as the interface you cast to. `JavaScriptSerializer` is rather old (possibly deprecated) and it is recommended to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) or another serializer nowadays.

However, if you have no choice but to use `JavaScriptSerializer` then you can annotate the properties and fields you don't want serialized with the [`ScriptIgnore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute.

In class `Stam`:

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public int b = 0;
```

Call as before but no need to cast:

```
Stam s = new Stam();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Console.WriteLine(jss.Serialize(s));
```

Output:

```
{"a":0}
```

---

If you need more flexibility, and again if you can't move to a more modern serializer, then you'll need to write a [JavaScriptConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter?view=netframework-4.8).